# Android Resource not found exception How to solve

Tags: android

Settingscreen.xml Not found But it is already in project How to solve

```
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/settingscreen.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f030017
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1916)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1871)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at com.test.Setting.onCreate(Setting.java:34)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     ... 11 more
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/layout/settingscreen.xml
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:486)
08-28 13:52:28.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4258):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1898)
```

Comment: Try to clean the project then run it.

Comment: ones exported apk then this error is coming

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether Settingscreen.xml is well formatted.
2. Check whether it is as part of the project.
3. Check whether Settingscreen.xml is there in the apk file.

if these things are proper, then clean the project and delete the gen folder and run it again.

Comment: error made after apk created and published in market and it comes rarely

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean your project and run again
and format your code